# Network request timeout or network lost or slow network not getting handle properly in codenameone

Tags: java, ios, codenameone

I have tried to call no of web services in a sequential manner like one by one as below. Once all web services run successfully task is over. If not then there must be showing the alert to the user.

Code:

```
Dialog progressDialog = ComponentUtils.getFormattedDialog(new Dialog());
progressDialog.showModeless();

boolean allDone = true;

for(int i=0;i<serviceList.size();i++){
    String serviceUrl = serviceList.get(i);
    boolean service = getServiceResponse(serviceUrl);
    if(service==false){
        progressDialog.dispose();
        allDone = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(allDone){
    progressDialog.dispose();
    Dialog.show("SUCCESS","Process Done","OK",null);
}
else{
    Dialog.show("FAIL","Process Failed","OK",null)
}

...


public static boolean getServiceResponse(String serviceUrl){
    boolean isSuccess = false;
    ConnectionRequest connectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest() { 
        @Override
        protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
            this.kill();
            LogUtil.setErrorLog(message,page_name+ " > handleErrorResponseCode");
            isSuccess = false
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleException(Exception err) {
            this.kill();
            LogUtil.setErrorLog(err,page_name + " > handleException");
            isSuccess = false
        }

        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input)  {
            isSuccess = true
        }
    };

    connectionRequest.setUrl(serviceUrl);
    connectionRequest.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    connectionRequest.setPost(true);
    connectionRequest.setDuplicateSupported(true);
    connectionRequest.setTimeout(100000);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(connectionRequest);

    return isSuccess;
}
```

Whenever I am trying to sync process in the full network it works fine as aspected.

But during the process, if network runs slow or lost then it will not tend to alert the user to the issue. instead, it just sticks on process dialog.

I have added error log in one file to check later on for the issue. But that also not showing any error in this case.

Any help will be more appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Timeout in Codename One is currently limited to connection timeout and doesn't apply to read timeout so once a connection is made it will last. You can use a progress listener on the `NetworkManager` to detect such situations and kill the connection.

Comment: @Shai-Thanks for suggestion. Actually i have my own progress bar with no action. So how to deal with this? And in this case of timeout, There is no error thrown in handleException or handleErrorResponseCode.

Comment: Timeout is problematic in that way, it behaves very differently in the various OS's